# RTA from microphone with wpf sound visualization library

Tags: c#, wpf, audio, naudio

I'm trying to make a basic Real Time (audio spectrum) Analyzer. I am trying to use C#/WPF and use the NAudio and WPF Sound Visualization Libraries. I am not sure that WPF Sound Visualization Library is capable of using an audio input such as Line In or a Microphone source, through something like WaveIn? I don't want to capture the audio, I just want to view real time data about frequency and intensity. Any suggestions?

Comment: You must capture the audio anyway, how do you want to view something if you don't capture it ? Now you have the choice of not saving the audio to your hard drive which is probably what you'll want to do. I don't really know NAudio but I know BASS.NET very well and this can be done very easily with it. http://www.un4seen.com/bass.html

Comment: I've heard the BASS.Net works well. I'll look into that. Thanks.

Comment: You can come back here and ask me for help if you can't get it to work.